# Entering formula in a cell generates Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I have searched the net for a solution and re-coded the VBA many times.
I ended up with manually filling a string (in bits because I always miscount the quotes):

```
PKHNTString = "=SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(AF:AF&AD:AD&AE:AE);" 
PKHNTString = PKHNTString + """ "";""" 
PKHNTString = PKHNTString + """)"
```

This results in a string containing : 
=SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(AF:AF&AD:AD&AE:AE);" ";"")
as can be found in the local vars:
    : PKHNTString : "=SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(AF:AF&AD:AD&AE:AE);" ";"")" : String

If I paste this exact value in the cell, it works (removes spaces and converts everything to uppercase), However when i put this formula in a cell through VBA like this:

```
NWS.Cells(j, 48).Formula = PKHNTString
```

I get the error: Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error.

Any help would be appreciated!

TIA,
Willem

Comment: Are you trying to do an array formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified a semi-colon (;) as the argument separator in your formula.  Via VBA, you always need to use a comma for that, no matter the current regional settings.  The .FormulaLocal does however need the localized version of the list separator.

Because the regional settings can and will vary between PC's, it's best to use the .Formula member and not .FormulaLocal - otherwise you'd have to use code to determine the correct list separator to use (can be done with some API calle, but it's more work than just using .Formula).

Therefore, either use .FormulaLocal, or replace the ";" with a "," (recommended).

Comment: Thanks Carl, FormulaLocal did the trick!, I Already tried to replace the ; by , but that didn't seem to work.Now that I tested it again, it did work also!
Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: @WillemSchulte: FormulaLocal will not be quite portable; when you run the same VBA code on a PC that has other regional settings (specifically the list separator), it'll stop working.  I've updated the answer with the details.  The replacement of the ";" with "," should work in combination with .Formula...

Comment: Thanks, I came to the same consideration and used the general notation with the ,. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape every inner " (quotation mark) in PKHNTString. For now, VBA is trying to insert `=SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(AF:AF&AD:AD&AE:AE);` as formula and doesn't know what `;"")` is. While inserting formula into a cell, your `PKHNTString` must be:

```
"=SUBSTITUTE(UPPER(AF:AF&AD:AD&AE:AE);"" "";"""")"
```

It's not easy to enter formula with " via VBA...

Comment: Thanks Egan, for your reply. The string was built correctly and I tried your code first. Since I usually fumble up the quotes, I tend to split de string to make sure it build up correctly. The actual error was caused by me NOT using FormulaLocal.